# Is Amazon Videos a profitable business and how?

Tags: production, distribution

A great number of shows and series are available "freely" to subscribers of services like Amazon Prime, etc.

Among these shows, many seem to have been produced exclusively for this platform, and even to have been produced very recently. 
I have the impression that producing this amount of high quality content must cost incredible amounts of money, that I do not feel the fees demanded by the service can support. 
Which parts am I missing that can explain the economic existence of such a service?

Comment: I guess the $99 I spend a year on Prime doesn't count as revenue?  Plus the movie rental / purchase revenue.  Now I'm not saying that its a profitable business, and Prime revenue is intertwined with the free-delivery perks etc but $99 a year is not far off the $180 a year that HBO Now costs.  HBO has a richer stream of recent movies and *very* expensive productions.

Comment: I don't have time immediately to write an answer - but your question made me look around, and indications are that it isn't profitable and is likely to be a loss leader.

Comment: The point isn't to be profitable, it's to create a platform that helps you lure customers.

Comment: They're taking a big gamble with Lord of the Rings -Their current five season price tag is said to be 1 Billion!! Then they ahve picked up a few more fantasy/sci-fi series so i am curious to see how that goes. They also just changed how they produce shows--picking up a season, instead of a Pilot.

Comment: Now I don't know how they make money of their streaming service alone, but you can buy channels and individual shows now too! Plus being a prime member is not just about streaming, but about other perks like 2-day FREE shipping on several items and the there are music perks and food perks too! It seems to be more complicated.

Comment: You have to spend money to make money.  Spend money to produce a quality program and people will want to pay to watch it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about 'Movies & TV' it's about a single content provider's financial model.

Comment: Shouldn't there be articles about Amazon Videos in online financial magazines that discuss their business model?  https://www.fool.com/investing/2017/02/22/amazon-prime-instant-video-is-a-huge-loss-leader.aspx     https://www.fool.com/investing/general/2016/03/25/how-prime-makes-amazon-profitable.aspx  https://www.google.com/search?q=amazone+videos+profitablity&oq=amazone+videos+profitablity&aqs=chrome..69i57.22934j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I don't know - I'm on the fence.  Questions about the business side of production and distribution of movies would seem to be on topic.  The changing business models cased by 'video on demand' like Netflix, Prime and the fact that the streamers have started to become producers of content too is quite interesting.

Comment: Even if this in on topic, I'm not sure how Amazon would even know if it's profitable.  I watch a few shows on Amazon, but even if I didn't I would still have prime.  They can tell how much of my money goes "towards" Prime Video.

Comment: I'd like to know why my helpful comment for a model comparison was unceremoniously deleted. That said, it's still in no way on topic here. Had the question been about some hicksville station's financial model, it would already be closed.

Comment: I found this today: https://www.reuters.com/article/us-amazon-com-ratings-exclusive/exclusive-amazons-internal-numbers-on-prime-video-revealed-idUSKCN1GR0FX