# Do movie studios make much money from streaming services?

Tags: netflix

Streaming services for music make notoriously little money for musicians unless you are a top tier selling artist. It can take thousands of streams to get the equivalent revenue that an album purchase would give them.

I understand that movie streaming services (Netflix, Amazon Prime, etc.) have to pay rights to movie studios to be able to stream for movies but how does that revenue compare to the revenue they made from older business models where people rent movies in a physical or digital form?

In short, is the new streaming business model as bad for movie studios as it is for musicians? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: Not really. The streaming service pays the studio for the right to stream. It must be assumed that the studio will demand a reasonably profitable price.

Comment: Duplicate https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89554/profit-of-movies-streamed-on-netflix?rq=1

Comment: @paulie That was a specific netflix question. This is much more general and, if it attracts any good answers, would be worth preserving.

Comment: The big difference between music streaming and movie streaming is that the music industry largely lost control of the deals they could do long before subscription services became mainstream. Plus, they do make, in aggregate, a ton of money from them despite this, just in a different way. Movies studios seem to retain much more control over their rights. So, I presume, they do deals that don't pay them per view but demand big money upfront for limited streaming rights.

Comment: @Paulie_D This isn't a duplicate of that question. I understand that Netflix and other streaming services have to pay licensing fees. I just added more detail to clarify that my question is whether the revenue that a movie studio will make with those licensing fees is comparable to the revenue they used to make from rentals.

Comment: @matt_black As I understand it, the music studios may make money in aggregate but the musicians do not. Maybe the difference is that all the people who make in movies (actors, directors, etc) tend to earn most of their money by being paid up front, where as musicians used to make money from a percentage of sales?

Comment: Movie and TV content isn't like Music.  Music can be created by an individual, even a large and successful musician has relatively low costs compared to creating a TV show or a movie.  The business model must be very different.

Comment: All good comments. While we don't have evidence of this the interpretation seems to be that ppl in movies get paid up front and studios take the profit or losses from successful or failing movies. This is also true in streaming so as long as they studio has some top streaming movie that services want, it balances out over the less valuable ones. Conversely, musicians earn on royalties and not upfront and their earnings are specific to their music. So a music label maybe ok w their streaming revenue since they have top tier and indie but individual musicians aren't.